# ¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar varios select al seleccionar el valor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Cómo puedo mostra y ocultar select con jQuery 
 por ejemplo tengo un select con valor 1 a 4 
ahora al elegir 2 me tiene que mostrar 2 select otro ejemplo
 si eligo 3 me tiene que mostar 3 select asi tambien al elegir 4 
me tiene que mostrar 4 select  gracias antemano

Aquí les dejo mi código que aún solo tengo para 2  
mi problema está al elegir 2 me muestra solo 1 select pero yo quiero que me muestre

SELECT

Habitacion

   1
   2
   3
   4




ADT

   2
   3
   4




CHD

   2
   3
   4
   5

CODIGO de JS

```
    $(function() {
        $('#Habitacion').change(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
           $('#' + $(this).val()).show();  
        });
    });
```

Como esto me debe salir al final [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende que es lo que deseas hacer ni que has hecho. Por favor complementa tu respuesta con código legible y verificable.

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres ocultar? no entiendo, que tal si lo gráficas para entenderte mejor.

Comment: Mi codigo hmtl no se porque no se muestra 
     Bueno  mi idea es mostrar y ocultar select al 
     al elegir un numero que esta en el option del select 
     por ejm elijo 2 entonces me tiene que mostrar 2 select 
     nose si me explico

Comment: mi codigo de html subí en imagen

Comment: Deberias de darte [un vuelta por el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi verias como tienes la opción de poner tu código html,css, javascript,php, etc... Y haciendo una pregunta mas organizada, seguro que te ayudaban. Suerte.

Comment: Creo q ya entendi lo q quieres. Para eso vas a tener q usar una funcion q se llama innerHtml. Con eso leerias cuantas habitaciones selecciono y generarias el html correspondiente. Tambien puedes hacerlo con jquery. Recuerda generarle ids distintos asi puedes referirte a ellos. Tambien concentrate en armar una pregunta entendible.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias voy a probarlo

Comment: Si vas a seguir la lógica de crear html desde js, yo pienso que deberías  crear esos selects desde un lenguaje de servidor, ya que no te servirán para nada mas que front end, y no podrás ejecutar sentencias ni enviar datos.

Comment: Así es estoy trabajando con asp.net MVC, C#, y todo los datos que tengo en select estoy jalando desde servidor con AJAX

Comment: Jorge Luis Cómo le mostraría en vez de <select> con sus <option> en vez de input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que interpreto de tu pregunta seria algo así lo que deberías implementar, te dejo un código simple para que puedas probarlo y a partir de el lo adaptes a la necesidad de tu requerimiento:

```js
$(function(){

  $("#mySelect").change(function(){
  var cantidad =$("#mySelect").val();
    $("#myInput").val(cantidad);
    RenderInputs(cantidad);
  });
  
  $("#myInput").change(function(){
  var cantidad = $("#myInput").val();
    $("#mySelect").val(cantidad);
    RenderInputs(cantidad);
  });

});

function RenderInputs(cantidad){
$('#content').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
  $('#content').append('<div class="col-6">');
        $('#content').append('<label> Input ' + (i+1) + '</label>');
        $('#content').append('<input class="form-control" type="text" id="input'+(i+1)+'"/>');
        $('#content').append('</div>');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <lavel>Cantidad</label>
      <select id="mySelect" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <label>Cantidad</label>
        <input id="myInput" class="form-control" type="number">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" id="content"></div>
```

Espero que te oriente! Saludos.